# Impossible recursive generic class definition?

Tags: c#

**Challenge:**
Please create an instance of the following class (using any type as T):

```
class Foo<T>
    where T : Foo<T>
{
}
```

You may use any technique you like; plain "new MyClass...", using reflection, hacking MSIL, whatever.

Comment: Giving insight on what you want to achieve may help people give better alternative answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive generic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647533/recursive-generic-types)

Comment: I really have no purpose of this weird construction. Frankly I didn't think it was possible, so it's cool that I got an answer. (And, no, it's not a homework question... ;-)

Comment: I actually had a purpose for this.  An interface that has a collection of itself, *e.g.* `interface IPerson<T> where T : IPerson<T> { IEnumerable<T> Subordinates }`.  Implementers of the interface will need Subordinates to be a collection of the concrete type `T`, otherwise they have all kinds of problems with co/contravariance of a generic collection.  IEnumerable<IPerson> would make things difficult.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Foo<Bar> foo = new Foo<Bar>();
    }
}
class Foo<T> where T : Foo<T> {}
class Bar : Foo<Bar> {}
```

Comment: Haha cool! I actually didn't think this was possible! Hehe. I stand corrected. Very nice indeed! :)