# Strange C# generic contraint

Tags: c#, generics, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Impossible recursive generic class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663189/impossible-recursive-generic-class-definition)

I just discovered that

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Foo<T>
{

}
```

is legal. What exactly does it mean? It seems
recursive and is it possible to instantiate something
like this?

Comment: These are referred to as "curiously recurring" generic constraints. See also: [Curiouser and curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx), by Eric Lippert, it is probably the best explanation you can get.

Comment: This is commonly used to get a type reference to the actual class. Example is IComparable, etc.

Comment: @AlvinWong, It's not totally useless. You can build tree-like structures like this, by adding properties to Foo which hold your values. Equally, Foo can be inherited, and therefore this constraint will allow any derivative of Foo also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that this is useless. Let's observe the below example how to support *fluent* syntax. In cases, that you are creating some `base` implementation in a **Parent** and would like to provide fluent declarations... you can use this constraint this way

```
public class Parent<TChild>
    where TChild : Parent<TChild>
{
    public string Code { get; protected set; }

    public TChild SetCode(string code)
    {
        Code = code;
        return this as TChild; // here we go, we profit from a constraint
    }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public Child SetName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        return this // is Child;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestFluent
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SetProperties()
    {
        var child = new Child();
        child
            .SetCode("myCode") // now still Child is returned
            .SetName("myName");

        Assert.IsTrue(child.Code.Equals("myCode"));
        Assert.IsTrue(child.Name.Equals("myName"));
    }
}
```

Please, take it just an example, of how this constraint could be used

Comment: Interesting example.  Not sure I like it - it still feels wrong, but I see that it *could* have some uses...