# Index into arbitrary nested Dictionary/List structure in C#

Tags: c#

I have a structure that is a `Dictionary<string,object>`, where the values are either strings, nested `Dictionary<string,object>` or a `Lists` of these nested dictionaries.  This structure is mostly a temp area to build something that will be converted to JSON.

If I want to make assertions on the contents of that structure, though, I can't easily do something like

```
foo["bar"][0]["baz"][1][2]["quux"]
```

without ridiculous type casting, and because the structure is not perfectly recursive, a solution like this ([Recursive generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647533/recursive-generic-types)) doesn't work.

What is the best option here?

Should I look at `dynamic`?
Should I replace the `Dictionary` instances with anonymous objects?
Should I looked at `ExpandoObject`?  etc.

Comment: It looks like you don't care about type safety here, so you could definitely use `dynamic`.

Comment: Yes, `dynamic` is what I want in this case - that should be the accepted answer.  The whole point is to effectively let me use duck typing with indexing into dictionaries/lists.  Only downside is that you still need casts for LINQ extension methods like `Select` and `Where` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are converting it to Json anyway just use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) it lets you do `foo["bar"][0]["baz"][1][2]["quux"]` out of the box and has other nice features like turning your object in to a properly formatted Json string once you are ready to turn it in to that.